# Adding URL images to mapbox GL JS Layers

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a layer on mapbox as follows;

```
map.addLayer({
   "id": "places-drink",
   "type": "symbol",
   "source": "places",
   "filter": ["all", ["==","Venues","TRUE"],['==','Type','drink']],
   "layout": {
           "icon-image": "bar-15",
           "icon-allow-overlap": true,
           "icon-size": 1.3
    },
});
```

and i want to instead of using the mapbox icons, use a local image. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Another approach that may be simpler in some cases is to use [Markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Marker) rather than Icons. The big difference I believe is that there's no collision avoidance with markers - they're always just stuck on the top of everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The `icon-image` property of symbol layers uses the style's sprite sheet to store icons.

There are a few you can modify the sprite sheet for your map style to include custom images. If you want to use local files, you'll need to use a tool like [spritezero](https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero-cli) to assemble a sprite sheet from your images and then set the [`sprite`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#root-sprite) url of your style to the location of the sprite sheet directory you created.

You can also upload your custom images to a style using mapbox.com/studio/ Style Editor. Here is a guide on how to do that: https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-images/

*Disclaimer - I work at Mapbox*

Comment: at the moment I have the follwoing in my style.json; "sprite": "markers.json", however this does not work.

Comment: mapbox-gl-js doesn't support relative URLs, so you'll have to include the full file path or URL. also it should point to a directory that includes the sprite sheets (regular and retina resolution) and the json file

Comment: This is my current directory structure; `web-app
├── ./package.json
├── ./public
│   ├── ./public/Cultured1
│   │   ├── ./public/Cultured1/license.txt
│   │   └── ./public/Cultured1/style.json
│   ├── ./public/sprite-sheet
│   │   ├── ./public/sprite-sheet/sprite.json
│   │   └── ./public/sprite-sheet/sprite.png
├── ./require.js
├── ./views/
├── ./bower_components/
├── ./routes/
├── ./semantic.json
└── ./server.js`  my style.json contains "sprite": "public/sprite-sheet", and as you can see my sprite-sheet directory contain the .json file and the .png file

Comment: Sorry can you confirm how I can reference the sheet? Is my directory structure correct? And how should I set up my style.json for my custom mapping style?

Comment: it would have to be something like `"sprite": "https://www.hosturl.com/public/sprite-sheet/"` if the app is live somewhere or `"sprite": "/User/name/Documents/project/public/sprite-sheet/"` if you're just serving it locally

Comment: Ok thanks, and that directory contains the sprite.json and the sprite.png?

Comment: I am now getting the following error; XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cultured-cities.com/public/sprite@2x.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. What should I do about this?